# docker service create container existing

Tags: docker

hello team when i create service in docker swarm , then with instantly containers are existing with 0 code  below are logs 
`Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 kernel: IPVS: Creating netns size=2040 id=417
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 NetworkManager[528]: <info>  [1519803156.2518] device (vethb31b4b5): link connected
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethb31b4b5: link becomes ready
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 kernel: docker0: port 3(vethb31b4b5) entered blocking state
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 kernel: docker0: port 3(vethb31b4b5) entered forwarding state
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.312181706Z" level=warning msg="unknown container" container=4ac8ae6d6f542a7a7b361f7249fd749eed9b6489155f3f051b0b4f5bbbb3d0b2 module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.330172710Z" level=warning msg="unknown container" container=4ac8ae6d6f542a7a7b361f7249fd749eed9b6489155f3f051b0b4f5bbbb3d0b2 module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.361597892Z" level=warning msg="unknown container" container=4ac8ae6d6f542a7a7b361f7249fd749eed9b6489155f3f051b0b4f5bbbb3d0b2 module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36Z" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=4ac8ae6d6f542a7a7b361f7249fd749eed9b6489155f3f051b0b4f5bbbb3d0b2 module="containerd/tasks"
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.402480985Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.402535187Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 kernel: docker0: port 3(vethb31b4b5) entered disabled state
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 NetworkManager[528]: <info>  [1519803156.4258] manager: (vethd1102f2): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4335)
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.425967110Z" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n"
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.425987752Z" level=info msg="Ignoring extra error returned from registry: unauthorized: authentication required"
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.426011251Z" level=error msg="pulling image failed" error="pull access denied for ubunut, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=6vd6hq8l81ztlpaih0xwn6y0v service.id=8yfn38lxo6ej2244vqbnx4m0k task.id=szdix3oeko8b8e7cyg0pwpjea
Feb 28 07:32:36 ip-172-31-18-123 dockerd: time="2018-02-28T07:32:36.426589500Z" level=erro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run any  foreground process in your docker image, then you can able to create service